# Insertion with only one column value changing

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this

```
Insert into abc(col1, col2, col3) select col1, 1, col3 from xyz where somecondition
Insert into abc(col1, col2, col3) select col1, 2, col3 from xyz where somecondition
Insert into abc(col1, col2, col3) select col1, 3, col3 from xyz where somecondition
Insert into abc(col1, col2, col3) select col1, 4, col3 from xyz where somecondition
...
```

So there is only second column value that is changing and all else are same.

Is there any better or compact way to do the above?
May be something in one query!

I am using MySql

**Edit:**

I am using this inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Create the table with col2 as AUTO_INCREMENT, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Thanks @ryanbwork, but actually this field is already in the database that actually stores grade id for my application those ranges from 1-9, so I want to handle the value of col2 manually as sometimes we may have record with only value 2 in col2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `somecondition` is the same and you need sequential numbers for `col2` you can do following:

```
INSERT INTO abc(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, @n := @n + 1, col3
FROM xyz, (SELECT @n:= 0) n
WHERE somecondition
```

**UPDATE**

If your `WHERE` conditions applied to `xyz` ensures that only one row will be returned and your `xyz` table has more than 9 records (although you can `CROSS` with any other table) you can leverage `CROSS JOIN` AND `LIMIT` to replicate your row N (9 in the example) times with single `INSERT-SELECT` statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO abc(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT t1.col1, @n := @n+1, t1.col3 
  FROM xyz AS t1 CROSS JOIN xyz AS t2,(SELECT @n:= 0) n 
WHERE t1.col2=2 LIMIT 9
```

Comment: Seems it is the answer I was looking for :) Let me just give it a try and I'll return and mark it as the best answer :) Thanks!

Comment: Didn't help :( it is inserting only one record, my actual query is this 
INSERT INTO assessmentperiodgrade(assessmentperiodid, gradeid) SELECT assessmentperiodid,(@n:=@n+1) AS gradeid FROM assessmentperiod, 
 (SELECT @n:=0) n WHERE createddate=@UTCDateTimeNow AND createduser=Username;

Comment: We didn't specify till when n should be incremented, can this be a reason? I want to insert 9 records

Comment: @PawanNogariya How many records returned when executing this query `SELECT assessmentperiodid FROM assessmentperiod WHERE createddate=@UTCDateTimeNow AND createduser=Username`?

Comment: One. As I want to insert same assessmentperiodid etc. from assessmentperiod table with only one column change i.e. grade id, so it would insert nine grades for same assessment

Comment: Thanks @peterm, I will be able to check it on Monday. I will update you then :)

Comment: Thanks Man! That worked! My final query becomes this now INSERT INTO assessmentperiodgrade(assessmentperiodid,gradeid)
SELECT ap.assessmentperiodid, @n := @n+1
  FROM assessmentperiod AS ap CROSS JOIN assessmentperiod AS ap1,(SELECT @n:= 0) n 
WHERE ap.createddate=@UTCDateTimeNow AND ap.createduser=Username LIMIT 9;

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure that loop into your queries like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```

I hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks BlackHatShadow, actually I am looking for some less code than I am using currently. I just have to do nine inserts.

Comment: Insert from where? is it from another table?